# Recursive with count sql

Tags: sql

i have one table

like this

```sql
id  prod_id     code               date    
1   AXDCFC      candy           2021-08-01 
2   WXEFRF      pop             2021-08-01 
3   QWASZX      mac             2021-08-01 
4   ZXCVVB      green           2021-08-01  
5   MNBVVC      cake            2021-08-02   
6   UIASGD      hamberger       2021-08-02
```

and i want to make this to add 0.50 to the total count of prod_id per day.

```sql
id  prod_id     code               date             cnt
1   AXDCFC      candy           2021-08-01         1.50
2   WXEFRF      pop             2021-08-01         2.50
3   QWASZX      mac             2021-08-01         3.50
4   ZXCVVB      green           2021-08-01         4.50
5   MNBVVC      cake            2021-08-02         1.50
6   UIASGD      hamberger       2021-08-02         2.50
```

i tried recursive in self-reference

```sql
WITH recursive q AS (
    SELECT prod_id, 1.5 as cnt, count(*) over() as total_count
    from product
    WHERE date = '2021-08-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT temp.prod_id, cnt + 1, total_count
    FROM product as temp
    JOIN q ON temp.prod_id = q.prod_id
    WHERE q.cnt < q.total_count
    
)

SELECT *
FROM q
```

and result.
Every row has the same value, one by one. How can I upload cnt by prod_id?

```sql
id  prod_id     code               date             cnt
1   AXDCFC      candy           2021-08-01         1.50
2   WXEFRF      pop             2021-08-01         1.50
3   QWASZX      mac             2021-08-01         1.50
4   ZXCVVB      green           2021-08-01         1.50
5   AXDCFC      candy           2021-08-01         2.50
6   WXEFRF      pop             2021-08-01         2.50
7   QWASZX      mac             2021-08-01         2.50
8   ZXCVVB      green           2021-08-01         2.50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*,
       (0.5 +
        row_number() over (partition by date, prod_id order by id)
       ) as total_count
from product p
```